# complex math routines in mysql

Tags: mysql, math

I have a table in Mysql that has field code with a `value = 'A'` that represents the type of sale of a part.  The sale price is displayed as `Price`.  There is a `Quantity` field that I need to multiply by the `Price`. The query `sum(quantity*price) where code='A'` gives me what I want.  I also have a `code = 'T'` that represents the tax of the sum of the transactions. I can get that easy enough by `sum(price) where code='T'`.  I need to subtract the value of the `'T'` (tax) value from the  `sum(quantity*price)`.

I can do this by looping through two separate queryies but I would like to combine into one query.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want from your description. Can you show some sample table data and the result you're looking for?

Comment: quantity    price    code

Comment: What is that supposed to mean? I asked for **data**, not just the column names.

Comment: Edit your question to show the table data.

Comment: Also, show a more complete example, e.g. with multiple `T` rows.

Comment: Sorry...This is my first time and I don't know how to structure the test I posted so when it went on line it was a mess.   Basically the math looks like (2+3) - .33

Comment: Use the code markdown tool `{}` in the SO editor.

Comment: Thanks Barmar I appreciate your reply

Answer (score 4):

You just want conditional aggregation:

```
select (sum(case when value = 'A' then quantity * price else 0 end) -
        sum(case when value = 'T' then price else 0 end)
       ) as netprice
```

Comment: looks like what I want..let me give it a try.  It gets me close to what I want but it was the structury of the query that I was looking for.  Thanks you so much.  Now, do you know of a series of tutorials that would teach me how to do more complex queries?

Comment: That is basically a select case function...I will study that.  Thanks for the help, I never thought of this.  I was thinking pure math.